# Karate: Run a Scenario file on two different url's

Tags: karate

I have a requirement in my project to run a Scenario file on two different urls. All the request headers for both the URL's are exactly the same.

Planning to use similar to below

```
Scenario Outline: Test

Given url <testurls>
And path 'test'
When method GET
    Examples:
        |testurls  |
        |'https://test1.com' |
        |'https://test2.com' |
```

Is there any other better way to handle it in Karate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the simplest way.